# HTML Form Library for PHP 5

Tags: php, html, forms

I am looking for a `QuickForm` replacement. QF has performance issues with, for example, many options in combobox. I would also like something more object oriented, like Zend_Form, but without decorators and so much bloat. Of course it should also be warning with `E_STRICT`. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 14):

You could try `\Nette\Forms\Form`, it's part of [Nette Framework](http://nette.org).

Documentation: http://doc.nette.org/en/forms

Answer (score 5):

A link to [QuickForm](http://pear.php.net/package/html_quickform/redirected) wouldn't have killed you...

Anyway, I was looking for a system to generate forms and then save the result into a database. The following are some systems I found.

- [Dataman](http://www.phpdevshed.com/forum/)
- [phpMyEdit](http://www.phpmyedit.org/)
- [PHP DataGrid](http://www.apphp.com/php-datagrid/index.php) Two versions, old one is free, new one not.
- [dadabik](http://www.dadabik.org/)

First system I found that did the sorts of things I wanted. But, doesn't do them quite how I want.
Doesn't have import.
Settings are stored in the db.
Easy to change the settings using web interface. Easy to modify table. 
Can not create tables.
Allows you to view multiple tables from the same interface easily. 
No multi-option. (Multi-choice.)

I then decided, what the hell, I would write my own, and I did. It isn't downloadable yet, but is in use.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the following free PHP form scripts:

- [phpAddEdit](http://www.phpaddedit.com)
- [Formitable - Form creation class](http://formitable.sourceforge.net/)
- [DaDaBIK](http://www.dadabik.org/)
- [FormHandler](http://www.formhandler.net/) [FormBuilder](http://FormBuilder)
- [Phorm](http://www.phorm.com/)
- [Phormation](http://www.peaceworks.ca/phormation.php)
- [phpFormGenerator](http://phpformgen.sourceforge.net/)
- [PHP Form - Processor](http://www.richardwillars.com/articles/php/php-form-processor/)
- [PHP HTML Form - Generation and Validation Class](http://stefangabos.blogspot.com/2006/12/zebra-php-framework-php-html-form.html)
- [phpMyEdit](http://www.phpmyedit.org/)
- [phpOpenFormGenerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpopenformgen/)
- Find more at [HotScripts.com](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/form-processors/)

If commercial software doesn't scare you check [PHPRunner](http://xlinesoft.com/phprunner/).

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't specify, I'm assuming you aren't using [QuickForm2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2), have you looked at this version of QuickForm?

http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2

Answer (score 3):

you could try [Zebra_Form](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-form/) - produces no error messages when error level is set to E_ALL, does both server- and client-side validation, has protection against cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks, protection against cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks, has [spectacular documentation](http://stefangabos.ro/wp-content/docs/Zebra_Form/Zebra_Form/Zebra_Form.html) and it's easy to learn;

Comment: should I make fake accounts? would that improve my answers? i'm linking to free, high-quality, LGPL-ed PHP libraries or jQuery plugins  representing answers to a particular questions

Comment: Please see [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) and [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022). Making fake accounts is a bad idea.  You must disclose your affiliation (if any) to the product in every answer you post.

Comment: @StefanGabos I'm using your Zebra Pagination php library and loving it, thank you! Couldn't find a way to contact you (comment sections on your website are closed up) - just needed to know if there's a way to add checkboxes to the pagination ? Currently a checkbox selection will only span a single page. Please let me know how I can contact you.

Answer (score 1):

Also you may take a look at [phorms](http://www.artfulcode.net/phorms/) and its [somewhat newer fork](https://github.com/jordanlev/phorms)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but the last time I researched this topic I did stumble up on on this: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/1.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Aura.Input](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Input). It is easy is to integrate and work with any frameworks / legacy code.

If you are interested to see some code how to write standalone form for PHP, have a look into http://harikt.com/phpform/

Comment: There is nothing called Aura.Input did it change name?

Comment: I have updated the link. It is actually a 1.x package which is currently listed in the home page ( http://auraphp.com/ ) of 1.x Packages.

Answer (score -1):

I've created Minacl - http://minacl.org - it's a bit different to most form libraries, you write HTML and it parses it so no decorators anywhere!  Think of it more as MVC for forms.