# Checking view for PHP variables

Tags: php, view

This is how I've been checking to see if variables are set when returned to my view.

```
<div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" <?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) { echo "value=\"". $_POST['username'] . "\""; } ?> />              
    <?php if(isset($username_error)) { echo "<label>" . $username_error . "</label>"; } ?>
</div>
```

I feel like there could be a better approach, or even a shorter way to check and echo out these values?

Comment: Because you're only adding the `label` element if `$username_error` is set, I don't know if there are ways to really speed this up. You'd still have to check for that variable, and I don't know if changing it to `if(@$username_error)` is worth the slight speed bump of generating an error.

Comment: (Fine print: I actually have no idea if generating that error is indeed slower.)

Comment: Does @$ = isset()? I'm not familiar with that syntax.

Comment: The `@` symbol suppresses errors that might be generated (and then echo'd to the user) by PHP. I haven't played around with it too much because I was kind of told it was a bad practice, so I'm not sure how many different kinds of errors it can stop from outputting to the screen. [More info on the `@` symbol in PHP.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Comment: You really shouldn't echo content back to the page like that. It opens you up to XSS security problems.

Comment: Are you talking about the value attribute and how it spits out the post value? The username_error label I think should be ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I deal with form submissions or possibly not initialized variables in PHP I do this:

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$username_error = usernameValid($username) ? true : false;
```

Then just echo out the username and do a quick if($username_error) to determine if you need to display the error. It's probably best to store if a submitted form field is valid or not and the error message separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could build the HTML independently, loading your template with [DOMDocument.loadHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and adding the attributes conditionally (JavaScript-like) via the DOM. That has the advantage of highlighting your HTML structure without as many inline checks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a library or framework that does the hard work for you.

See:

[A PHP and jQuery form creation and validation library available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362842/a-php-and-jquery-form-creation-and-validation-library-available)

[HTML Form Library for PHP 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910708/html-form-library-for-php-5)