# What's the best way of escaping quotes in a php script that saves to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm going back and forth with this, so I figured I'll ask here. I'm hoping for a single technique that will work for all input fields (text, select, textarea).

1. First we process user input using php script. There could be some validation errors so form may need to be redisplayed with user entered values. `htmlspecialchars($fieldValue, ENT_QUOTES)` doesn't work here because if there is a validation error and form is redisplayed, all quotes entered by user are converted to \". At least in a text area.
2. Once the form is validated successfully, we need to send input to the database. Column values need to be 'safe' so some conversion is required. I understand I may need to apply some form of conversion when reading from database, as well, although I hope to be wrong on this one.

Looking for a good practice that does not involved too much code.

===

Just as an update. In a Domino form, there is no escaping of any kind and no special processing is required. Notes just does it for it automagically. In a Java application that uses JPA, all of this 'safety' is handled automagically, as well. I understand that php may not have the equivalent but this is such a common issue that I choose to believe I'm missing some very simple solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to filter input that needs to go in DB!

Comment: you chose to ignore step #1. Once that's addressed, we can check if mysql_real_escape_string() does the rest.

Comment: He is answering a question that you are unable to solve, even if it only answers part of your question, say thanks and move on. Maybe the poster was not able to answer that question, so you can leave it up to another member. There is no need to be rude about this. You did not even post anything that you may have tried yourself, or what you are having problems with specifically, as is how questions in this community are generally asked. +1 for answer.

Comment: Please don't recommend any `mysql_*` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix for the `\"` problem, turn `magic_quotes` off, which you [shouldn't be using anyway](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php).

For your other problem, use a [driver that supports prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), and if you are looking for a JPA equivalent [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483080/php-developer-looking-for-solutions-equivalent-to-java-ee-architecture) and instead [use an ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library).

For validating user input in forms, [use a form library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910708/html-form-library-for-php-5) which will take care of these mundane tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ORM like Doctrine to do a lot of stuff automatically. You really should be using PDO for DB access, which will allow you to do "binding" instead of "escaping". Just using escaping can get problematic with UTF8 characters and encoding.